# In Visual Studio Code, with Dart, comments after a { are forced to a new line

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, comments, autoformatting

I'm coding in Dart, using Visual Studio Code. If I write a comment after a { on the same line, VSC moves it to the beginning of the next line. I want it on the same line to keep my code more condensed.

So, for instance, I want to write

```
if(           ) {      // when the email is not yet known ...
```

But this gets reformatted as:

```
if(           ) { 
    // when the email is not yet known ...
```

I found a similar question in 2019 (unanswered), and suggestions to turn off formatting -- but I want formatting 99.9% of the time, I just want this behavior deactivated.

So can a Dart or VSC expert out there please tell me what I need to do to fix this? I'd be most grateful ...

Comment: Visual Studio code and other ides that support dart use the [dart format](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format) command line tool that comes with the dart language. [The formatter does not support much configuration by design](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-configure-it). "This may be surprising, but the goal of dartfmt is not to automatically make your code look the way you like. It's to make everyone's Dart code look the same."

Comment: Thanks for that, mmcdon20. I did file an issue, and I think my arguments - fewer lines of code, comments not getting munged in with the code (separation of concerns!) and a paean to marginalia, adored by editors for over 500 years  - *surely* will do the trick 

Comment: You might want to edit the issue you filed. Both of your code examples look to be formatted the same way.

Comment: That is so ironic! In Visual Studio Code, I want the comment to stay on the same line, and it won't: and then when I complain about it in GitHub, the latter forces the comment (which I had typed on the next line) to appear on the same line! Arrrgh! Thanks for letting me know, mmcdon20.